# In SPI, How to count the frequency of the clock signal "sckl" from the master to the slave using VHDL?

Tags: fpga, spi, master-slave

I have created SPI master and slave modules and the connection is working fine but for verification purposes I would like to know how the slave could possibly determine the count of the output clock, sclk, that has been sent by the master.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since an SPI slave **receives** the clock signal from the master, it does not need to *determine* a baud rate.

If the master generates a clock signal of 1 MHz, the baud rate is 1 Mbps, as MOSI and MISO are one bit wide. The slave's shifters are driven by this clock signal.

Comment: First, thanks for your reply. Second, yes I know it's not like the UART but if I want to know it how this could be done?

Comment: Why do you think the slave needs to determine the baudrate?

Comment: The thing is, I would like to configure the master with different baud rates and I wanna check if these baud rates were generated correctly. I would be grateful if you could give me a hint about how this can be done.

Comment: Why do you want to use the slave to check that the master generates the expected clock? Commonly you write a test bench with an instance of the master as the test object.

Comment: Because I wanna have a universal master that can be configured with different slave types. Each slave could have its own constraints regarding the received sclk signal from the master or data width, etc. That's why in my testbech I instantiated many DUT to test, for instance, the slave with different data width and now I wanna test different baud rates. I hope that could me some sense now :)

Comment: So actually your question does not target how a slave determines the baud rate, but how to write a frequency counter for the master's clock. This is a completely different issue, and does not involve a slave. Well, writing a good question is a difficult task. ;-) Been there, had the same problem, as non-native English speaker.

Comment: You're right, the question needs to be modified. But thank you very much for your time and support :)

Answer (score 0):

As busybee has already stated, the SPI slave port receives a clock from the master. It is agnostic of the actual frequency, it's logic is tied to the transmitted clock.

However, your comments indicate that you want the slave to measure the baud rate of the SPI serial link. Typically this wouldn't be done in the SPI port, but in another module. You can route the SPI clock to this other module and use a second independent clock to count the clock edges between the rising edges of the SPI clock.

For example:
SCLK is running at 1MHz. The slave system clock is running at 50MHz. To determine the SCLK rate we count the number of system clock rising edges between each SCLK rising edge. This will be 50. We then divide by our known system clock frequency to get our SCLK frequency.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's really helpful!

Comment: Hey again Vance, Could you please give me a reliable source where I can find an example of creating a counter for counting the raising edges of the system clock?

Answer (score 0):

slave clk freq = master_clk_freq / ((divider + 1) *2)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).